# Using a PHP Function in a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli

Pretty much I have a function that converts a string to a URL friendly string.

Example: `$string = "Hello World!"`, when passed through my function, it would read `url($string) = "hello-world"`

So what I want to do is find in my database where the row = "hello-world"
But my databases aren't formatted like that so I want to pretty use my function is the sql query.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE url(row) = 'hello-world'";
```

I don't know if this is possible or not. I know I could get the results use the function and then pass it though the database again. But I was hoping there was a simpler way.

By the way I am using MySQLi Procedural if it makes a difference.

Comment: does your function `url()` return a string?

Comment: This is my function: `function url($url) {
    $url = preg_replace('~[^\\pL0-9_]+~u', '-', $url);
    $url = trim($url, "-");
    $url = iconv("utf-8", "us-ascii//TRANSLIT", $url);
    $url = strtolower($url);
    $url = preg_replace('~[^-a-z0-9_]+~', '', $url);
    return $url;
}`

So yes it does

Comment: what is the purpose of running through this function?

Comment: You can/will have to use a mysql function to do this for you.

Comment: @Idealcastle Pretty much I using a GET from the url and searching for a blog post of the title, I know I could do it by id too. But I guess I'm just picky and want it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your function within the query string itself like this, it allows the function to be used like a string and prints in the "field" you type in, then your function can escape the characters and presets, then returns the string.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".url("field")." = 'hello-world'";
```